# PHP Pushing to array issue

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build an array then traverse it but keep getting undefined index errors. What am I doing wrong here? Is the array not built correctly? If I don't push new items into it, the code works fine. As soon as I add more elements into it, the whole thing breaks.

```
foreach($CustPOIDs as $key => $val){
                    $CustPOID = $val['CustPOID'];
                       //Call this method for each CustPOID
                    $tender = new BOL($CustPOID);
                    $pickUpData[]=$tender->getPickupInfo();
                }
            }

           foreach ($pickUpData as $key => $val) {
                $LoadDate = $val['POLineLoadDate'];
                $POLineComments = $val['POLineComment'];
                $ProdID = $val['ProdID'];
                $ShipperId = $val['ShipperId'];
                $ShipDesc = $val['Description'];
                $shAddress = $val['Address1'];
                $shState = $val['State'];
                $shPhone = $val['Phone'];
                $pdProdDesc = $val['ProdDesc'];
                $pdCommodity = $val['Commodity'];
                $pdWeight = $val['ProdWeight'];
            }
```

---

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=12)
          'POLineLoadDate' => string '1969-12-31 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'POLineComment' => string '56sent NOT 60' (length=13)
          'ProdID' => string '322' (length=3)
          'ShipperId' => null
          'Description' => null
          'Address1' => null
          'City' => null
          'State' => null
          'Phone' => null
          'ProdDesc' => string 'SLESS 60CT Bin/Bin WMELON US#1' (length=30)
          'Commodity' => string 'WATERMELON' (length=10)
          'ProdWeight' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=12)
          'POLineLoadDate' => string '1900-01-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'POLineComment' => string '' (length=0)
          'ProdID' => string '192' (length=3)
          'ShipperId' => null
          'Description' => null
          'Address1' => null
          'City' => null
          'State' => null
          'Phone' => null
          'ProdDesc' => string 'RND WHT US#1 SIZE A PAPR POTAT' (length=30)
          'Commodity' => string 'POTATO' (length=6)
          'ProdWeight' => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=12)
          'POLineLoadDate' => string '1900-01-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'POLineComment' => string '' (length=0)
          'ProdID' => string '187' (length=3)
          'ShipperId' => null
          'Description' => null
          'Address1' => null
          'City' => null
          'State' => null
          'Phone' => null
          'ProdDesc' => string 'IDAHO US#1 6-10OZ POLY POTATO' (length=29)
          'Commodity' => string 'POTATO' (length=6)
          'ProdWeight' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: "*but keep getting undefined index errors.*" — Please post the exact error messages.

Comment: You've got an extra close curly bracket in your first foreach -- probably just leftover from the rest of your code but thought I'd point it out

Comment: The extra curly bracket is for a conditional above it.           Notice: Undefined index: POLineLoadDate in C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxx\takeIII\lEditor.php on line 245
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 211552 {main}( ) ..\lEditor.php:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the array has an extra level that's being overlooked... Maybe try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pickUpData); $i++) {
  foreach ($pickUpData[$i] as $key => $val) {
    $LoadDate = $val['POLineLoadDate'];
    $POLineComments = $val['POLineComment'];
    $ProdID = $val['ProdID'];
    $ShipperId = $val['ShipperId'];
    $ShipDesc = $val['Description'];
    $shAddress = $val['Address1'];
    $shState = $val['State'];
    $shPhone = $val['Phone'];
    $pdProdDesc = $val['ProdDesc'];
    $pdCommodity = $val['Commodity'];
    $pdWeight = $val['ProdWeight'];
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked really well, but my question persists... Why when I am building an array why is there an extra level? Am I building arrays incorrectly?

Comment: @Waragi no I don't think you're building them "incorrectly" so to speak... Probably what's happening is `$tender->getPickupInfo()` comes back as an array also. In fact you could probably achieve the same results using your original code but replacing `$pickUpData[]=$tender->getPickupInfo();` with something like this: `$pickUpInfo[$key]=$tender->getPickupInfo(); $pickUpData[]=$pickUpInfo[$key][0];`